# VBA Excel - Extract data from Column C and place into Column D

Tags: excel, vba

I have tons of text in Column C and only need to extract a portion. I can do it in Excel, but would like it in VBA. Here is how I do it in Excel

```
=MID(C2,FIND("IAV",C2)+6,11)
```

Here's a snippet of the information in 3 cells (broken up by the lines):

CVE: CVE-2013-3378

BID: 60681

Crossref: OSVDB #94438, IAVA #2013-A-0126

Vulnerability Publication Date: 2013/06/19

Patch Publication Date: 2013/06/19

Plugin Publication Date: 2013/07/24

---

CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows
cpe:/a:microsoft:silverlight

CVE: CVE-2013-3896

BID: 62793

Crossref: OSVDB #98223, MSFT #MS13-087, IAVB #2013-B-0117

Vulnerability Publication Date: 2013/10/08

Patch Publication Date: 2013/10/08

---

BID: 25628

Crossref: OSVDB #34600, OSVDB #43371, IAVT #2008-T-0046, CWE #20

Vulnerability Publication Date: 2007/09/05

Patch Publication Date: 2007/09/05

Plugin Publication Date: 2011/10/04

---

My goal is to extract anything following IAVA #, IAVB #, and IAVT #. So I am only left with 
2013-A-0126
2013-B-0117
2008-T-0046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cheated and assumed that I could search for "IAV" and add 6 characters to find the beginning of the string. Also, the column number is set as a variable.

```
Sub Test()
Dim ColNumber As Integer
ColNumber = 3 'Set the column you wish to run on

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
LastCell = Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, ColNumber).End(xlUp).Row

For TheRow = 1 To LastCell
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(TheRow, ColNumber + 1).Value = Mid(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(TheRow, ColNumber).Value,    InStr(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(TheRow, ColNumber).Value, "IAV") + 6, 11)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=MID(C2,FIND("IAV",C2)+6,11)
```

MID remains the same in VB, FIND becomes InStr, so this formula translates to:

```
StringVariable = Mid([C2],InStr([C2],"IAV") + 6, 11)
```

To write the answers in Column D, for each cell in column C...

```
Option Explicit
Sub WriteData()
Dim RowNum as Long
Dim LastRow as Long
Dim DataString as String

LastRow = Range("C1").End(xldown).Row

For RowNum=2 to LastRow
    DataString= Cells(RowNum,3) ' 3 = C
    Cells(RowNum,4)=Mid(DataString,InStr(DataString,"IAV") + 6, 11)
Next RowNum
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect. But how do I write it to do each Cell in Column C? I tested this and it works perfect for cell C2. Mind you, I really stink at programming. Just trying to get something that will work.